# Grabbing the posts from all the users that I am following

Tags: php, while-loop, posts

So I made a following system and that is obviously based around the users that exist in my "users" table. I just a made a posts system where users can post things. I am trying to make a feed where the user (user1) get the posts from all the users that (user1) is following (user2, user3, etc.). This is what I have so far

```
//Query for the people that I am following
$getfollowing = mysqli_query($dbconx, "SELECT * FROM follows WHERE follower='$log_username'");
while($rowf = mysqli_fetch_array($getfollowing)){
    $following = $rowf['followed'];
    $follower = $rowf['follower'];
}
//Query for the post of the people that the logged in user is following
    $query = mysqli_query($dbconx, "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE username='$following' OR username='$log_username' ORDER BY posttime DESC");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        $user = strip_tags($row['username']);
        $title = strip_tags($row['posttitle']);
        $post = strip_tags($row['post']);
        $time = strip_tags($row['posttime']);

        $time = date('<font color="#C3C3C3">l F j, Y</font> | g:ia', strtotime($time));
        $query2 = mysqli_query($dbconx, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$user'");
        $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($query2);
        $fname = $row2['fullname'];
        $ava = $row2['avatar'];
        //User picture
        $pic = '<img src="user/'.$user.'/'.$ava.'" width="100" height="100" style="border: 1px solid #000;" alt="'.$user.'">';
        if($ava == NULL){
            $pic = '<img src="images/avatardefault.jpg" height="100" width="100" style="border: 1px solid #000;" alt="'.$user.'">';
        }
```

I am able to get my posts and ONLY get the posts from ONE other user that I follow. How can get all the posts from all the users that I follow instead of just one of them?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen What do you mean by that? I didnt include what the posts actually look like or the ending '}' but how would I nest a loop?

Comment: Put the loop where you get and process posts inside the loop where you're getting and processing the users.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen that then duplicates my posts while getting everyone else's posts once

Comment: Check your conditions in your second query.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen yeah I have tried everything. This what you suggested and what I had before were the closest I have gotten so far. Nothing else is working